# C++ console change text position

Tags: c++, console-application

I'm still new to C++ so bear with me.

I'm currently making console output applications and I want to make a simple matrix calculator. So I want the user to input 4 values for each element of the matrix. Each element should be at a different xy position on the screen. So it makes up a square, a simple 2x2 matrix.

I don't have a clue how to change the position of text in C++ though. I used the Pascal programming languages before and all you had to do was 'gotoXY(20,40)' followed by a statement.

I know this is probably an easy question, I can't seem to work it out though.

Comment: Why dont you use `\t` for alignment?

Comment: You're right I could do that. Thanks.

Comment: @ACB It's better to use `std::setw()` for that.

Comment: @MarkGarcia  I just suggested an easy method . Not an answer

Answer (score 0):

If this is on Windows, you should use `SetConsoleCursorPosition`. I think I have the right helper class for you here: [Helper Class for Console Functions](http://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2008/11/28/helper-class-for-console-functions/).

Comment: That's just what I want, thanks!